# PHP: How to carry over data to another page after mysql read using while loop

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I have a slight dilemma on my hands. This is the situation. On a webpage, I am using a php while loop to read data into a page from a database. That works fine but I need each of this items when clicked, go to another webpage with more info on them. This 'more info' is just data that i will have on another column in database so its no biggie. So my dilemma is how do I know which item is clicked. Is there a way to track which unique index was clicked? (Keep in mind that I might me listing thousands of items on the page).

This is my while loop code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<div class="thumb">';
 echo '<a href="template.php"><img src='.$row['dresses_pic'].'/></a>';
 echo '<p>'.$row['price_'].'</p>';
 echo '</div>';
}
```

I have tried putting a SESSION inside the while loop but the next page always reads the last listing as the item. 
Is there a better way to achieve what am trying to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append the ID of the item to your link and then you can get it from the next page as a `$_GET` variable:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<div class="thumb">';
 echo '<a href="template.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><img src='.$row['dresses_pic'].'/></a>';
 echo '<p>'.$row['price_'].'</p>';
 echo '</div>';
}
```

**template.php**

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id']; // Use this to get the item from the DB
```

Comment: I am trying to use this now does this code still work it does not seem to be working for me, could you help?

Comment: @littleswany [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and be sure to post the code you have written so far.

Comment: My question asking is blocked is there any other way?

Comment: @littleswany You just have to wait until the block is lifted.

Comment: how long does that take?

Comment: @littleswany Not sure. Never been blocked. Sorry. :/

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in the ID of the row item and THEN retrieve the data for that ID on the new page.

```
 echo '<a href="template.php?id='.$row['id'].'"><img src='.$row['dresses_pic'].'/></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the id of the record to the next page(Use url parameter is most simple, `?id=xxx`), and query the db use the id (You could get it by `$_GET['id']`) to get the info.

Answer (score 1):

Use a query string to pass the item ID to your template.php page.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo '<div class="thumb">';
 echo '<a href="template.php?id='.$row['item_id'].'"><img src='.$row['dresses_pic'].'/></a>';
 echo '<p>'.$row['price_'].'</p>';
 echo '</div>';
}
```

See altered line above...